# Why my button doesn't change inner text with method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pug

I've tried to use a method, to change the inner text of Edit button to Save after it's being clicked but it doesn't seem to work. I need a little assistance.

```
b-button.editbtn.d-flex.flex-row.mb-3(@click="editBlood")
                    p.mb-0.text-white.p-1#editbtns Edit
```

```
editBlood() {
      this.edit = !this.edit
      if(this.edit == !this.edit) {
        document.getElementById('editbtns').text = "Save";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('editbtns').text = "Edit";
      }
```

Comment: What button? How is the function being called?

Comment: `if(this.edit == !this.edit)` - How can a value ever equal the opposite of itself?  What's the actual condition you're trying to express there?

Comment: I have also column which changes text to inputs. Now i want to also my button text to change from edit to save.
`.col-md-3
    input.form-control(type="text" v-model="test.result" v-if="edit")
        span.value(v-if="!edit")`

Answer (score 1):

Declare a local prop and store the text there instead of trying to re-target the element to set its innerText prop.

```
<template> 
 <button @click="editBlood">{{ text }}</button>
</template> 

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    button: {
      text: 'My button text'
    },
  },
  methods: {
    editBlood: function() {
      this.button.text = "new text!";
    },
  }
</script>
```